# Custom error pages in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to implement own error pages in MVC 5.
 Found one very interesting post about it -> [source](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages).

In it author advice to add `.aspx` page.

So my questions

Should i add `.aspx` page or `.cshtml` page (cause i work with `Razor`) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use static files, but if you want to use a dynamic file in the way that the blog entry you point to shows, you need to use an aspx file.